# REGEX - Letter and space but minimum one letter

Tags: php, regex

Following my regex:

```
/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/
```

It authorizes only letters and spaces, but how to make sure that there is at least one letter and a maximum of 30 characters including letters and spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this lookahead based regex:

```
/^(?=[^A-Za-z]*[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z\s]{1,30}$/
```

Comment: @user3022323: Yes I know this reges should work but I was surprised by unexplained down vote.

Comment: he/she might be confused by the fact you first tell it to not accept A-Za-z and then tell it to accept just that... (I don't really understand aswell.)

Comment: @CasNouwens: That is lookahead which just makes sure there is at least one letter in the regex. So 0 or more non-letter followed by single letters ensures at least 1 letter is present.

Comment: @anubhava so if I understand correctly, the lookahead 'scans' the whole input. and then continues on with testing the rest of the input with everything behind the lookahead?

Comment: It doesn't scan the full input. It looks ahead until it gets what it is looking for.

Answer (score -1):

1. Start at the beginning
2. Look ahead to ensure there's a letter somewhere.
3. Check that there are 1 to 30 characters.
4. Check that there are only letters or a space until the end

`/^(?= {0,29}[A-z])[A-z ]{1,30}$/`

---

EDIT: Used to accept all whitespace. Changed that to a regular space.

Comment: This doesn't allow space at the begining of the string.

Comment: Character class `[A-z]` includes `[`,`\\`,`]`,`^`, `_` and `\``